# Angular angular2-draggable ngDraggable drop event not firing

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the angular2-draggable library in an Angular 14 project:

```
"angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2"
```

When I have a normal draggable element, like this:

```
<span draggable="true"> Normal Draggable</span>
```

I can drag it over another element that listens for dragover and drop events, like this:

```
<div (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">Drop Area</div>
```

When I drop the normal draggable on the Drop Area, the dragover and drop events fire as expected.

However, when I have an element marked with "ngDraggable", like this:

```
<span ngDraggable >ngDraggable</span>
```

and I try to do the same thing, neither the dragover nor the drop events fire.

The angular2-draggable library is working great for multiple things I'm doing, but I need to know when an element is dropped on another.

Does anyone know whether/how this can be done?

Thanks much in advance.